# How to change color of text based on $value

Tags: php, html

I would like to change color of my `$` based on `$value`: red if it is below 10% and otherwise black. Part of the code that gives me resoult looks like this.

```
<td style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">'.round(100 * ($data[$tabele[$i]][$keys[$tabele[$i]][0]] + $data[$tabele[$i]]["RESERVED"] + $data[$tabele[$i]]["BIZ_AVAILABLE"]) / ArraySum($data[$tabele[$i]]) ,2).'%</td>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your calculation in a variable and then add a condition to your style to change colour vased on value of you variable. (e.g.:

```
<?php $value = round(100 * ($data[$tabele[$i]][$keys[$tabele[$i]][0]] + $data[$tabele[$i]]["RESERVED"] + $data[$tabele[$i]]["BIZ_AVAILABLE"]) / ArraySum($data[$tabele[$i]]) ,2)); ?>

<td style="font-weight: bold; color: <?php if($value<10):?>red<?php else:?>black<?php endif;?>;"><?php echo $value?>%</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $value = round(100 * ($data[$tabele[$i]][$keys[$tabele[$i]][0]] + $data[$tabele[$i]]["RESERVED"] + $data[$tabele[$i]]["BIZ_AVAILABLE"]) / ArraySum($data[$tabele[$i]]) ,2)); 

if($value<10)
echo '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">'.$value.'%</td>';
else
echo '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">'.$value.'%</td>';

?>
```